# How to use cut and paste commands as a single line command without using grep,sed awk, perl?

Tags: linux, unix

NOTE: avoid command **grep, sed awk, perl**

In Unix, I am trying to write a sequence of cut and paste commands (saving result of each command in a file) that inverts every name in the file(below) shortlist and places a coma after the last name(for example, bill johnson becomes johnson, bill).

here is my file shortlist:

```
2233:charles harris  :g.m.     :sales     :12/12/52: 90000
9876:bill johnson    :director :production:03/12/50:130000
5678:robert dylan    :d.g.m.   :marketing :04/19/43: 85000
2365:john woodcock   :director :personnel :05/11/47:120000
5423:barry wood      :chairman :admin     :08/30/56:160000
```

I am able to cut from shortlist but not sure how to paste it onto my filenew file in same command line. Here is my code for cut:

```
cut -d: -f2 shortlist
```

result:

```
charles harris
bill johnson
robert dylan
john woodcock
barry wood
```

Now I want this to be pasted in my filenew file and when I cat filenew, result should look like below,

```
harris, charles
johnson, bill
dylan, robert
woodcock, john
wood, barry
```

Please guide me through this. Thank you.

Comment: Any luck with the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` and `column`:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*|:' '{$2=$2","$3;$3=""}' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

With **`cut` and `paste` only** (and [process substitution `<(cmd)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)):

```
$ paste -d, <(cut -d: -f2 file | cut -d' ' -f2) <(cut -d: -f2 file | cut -d' ' -f1)
harris,charles
johnson,bill
dylan,robert
woodcock,john
wood,barry
```

If **process substitution** is **not available** in your shell (since it's not defined in POSIX, but is supported in `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh`), you use named pipes, or easier, save the intermediate result to files (`first` holding first name, `last` holding last name only):

```
$ cut -d: -f2 file | cut -d' ' -f1 >first
$ cut -d: -f2 file | cut -d' ' -f2 >last
$ paste -d, last first
```

If you need to also **include a space between** the last and first name, you can `paste` from three sources (middle one being a null source, like `/dev/null`, or shorter `<(:)` - null command in a process substitution), and reusing delimiters from a list of two (comma and space):

```
$ paste -d', ' <(cut -d: -f2 file | cut -d' ' -f2) <(:) <(cut -d: -f2 file | cut -d' ' -f1)
harris, charles
johnson, bill
dylan, robert
woodcock, john
wood, barry
```